# Audio Recording AudioQueueStart buffer never filled

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, aac

I am using AudioQueueStart in order to start recording on an iOS device and I want all the recording data streamed to me in buffers so that I can process them and send them to a server.

Basic functionality works great however in my BufferFilled function I usually get < 10 bytes of data on every call. This feels very inefficient. Especially since I have tried to set the buffer size to 16384 btyes (see beginning of startRecording method)

How can I make it fill up the buffer more before calling BufferFilled? Or do I need to make a second phase buffering before sending to server to achieve what I want?

```
OSStatus BufferFilled(void *aqData, SInt64 inPosition, UInt32 requestCount, const void *inBuffer, UInt32 *actualCount) {
    AQRecorderState *pAqData = (AQRecorderState*)aqData;

    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithBytes:inBuffer length:requestCount];

    *actualCount = inBuffer + requestCount;

    //audioData is ususally < 10 bytes, sometimes 100 bytes but never close to 16384 bytes    


    return 0;
}

void HandleInputBuffer(void *aqData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer, const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime, UInt32 inNumPackets, const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDesc) {
    AQRecorderState *pAqData = (AQRecorderState*)aqData;

    if (inNumPackets == 0 && pAqData->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket != 0)
        inNumPackets = inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize / pAqData->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket;

    if(AudioFileWritePackets(pAqData->mAudioFile, false, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize, inPacketDesc, pAqData->mCurrentPacket, &inNumPackets, inBuffer->mAudioData) == noErr) {
        pAqData->mCurrentPacket += inNumPackets;
    }

    if (pAqData->mIsRunning == 0)
        return;

    OSStatus error = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(pAqData->mQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}


void DeriveBufferSize(AudioQueueRef audioQueue, AudioStreamBasicDescription *ASBDescription, Float64 seconds, UInt32 *outBufferSize) {
    static const int maxBufferSize = 0x50000;

    int maxPacketSize = ASBDescription->mBytesPerPacket;
    if (maxPacketSize == 0) {
        UInt32 maxVBRPacketSize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
        AudioQueueGetProperty(audioQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MaximumOutputPacketSize, &maxPacketSize, &maxVBRPacketSize);
    }

    Float64 numBytesForTime = ASBDescription->mSampleRate * maxPacketSize * seconds;
    *outBufferSize = (UInt32)(numBytesForTime < maxBufferSize ? numBytesForTime : maxBufferSize);
}

OSStatus SetMagicCookieForFile (AudioQueueRef inQueue, AudioFileID   inFile) {
    OSStatus result = noErr;
    UInt32 cookieSize;

    if (AudioQueueGetPropertySize (inQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, &cookieSize) == noErr) {
        char* magicCookie =
        (char *) malloc (cookieSize);
        if (AudioQueueGetProperty (inQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, magicCookie, &cookieSize) == noErr)
            result = AudioFileSetProperty (inFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, cookieSize, magicCookie);
        free(magicCookie);
    }
    return result;
}


- (void)startRecording {

    aqData.mDataFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mSampleRate       = 22050.0;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = 0;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket   = 0;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame    = 0;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = 1024;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mFormatFlags      = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Main;
    AudioFileTypeID fileType             = kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType;
    aqData.bufferByteSize = 16384;


    UInt32 defaultToSpeaker = TRUE;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(defaultToSpeaker), &defaultToSpeaker);

    OSStatus status = AudioQueueNewInput(&aqData.mDataFormat, HandleInputBuffer, &aqData, NULL, kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &aqData.mQueue);
    UInt32 dataFormatSize = sizeof (aqData.mDataFormat);      

    status = AudioQueueGetProperty(aqData.mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_StreamDescription, &aqData.mDataFormat, &dataFormatSize);
    status = AudioFileInitializeWithCallbacks(&aqData, nil, BufferFilled, nil, nil, fileType, &aqData.mDataFormat, 0, &aqData.mAudioFile);

    for (int i = 0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {
        status = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer (aqData.mQueue, aqData.bufferByteSize, &aqData.mBuffers[i]);
        status = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (aqData.mQueue, aqData.mBuffers[i], 0, NULL);
    }

    aqData.mCurrentPacket = 0;                           
    aqData.mIsRunning = true;                            

    status = AudioQueueStart(aqData.mQueue, NULL);
}
```

**UPDATE:** I have logged the data that I receive and it is quite interesting, it almost seems like half of the "packets" are some kind of header and half is sound data. Could I assume this is just how the AAC encoding on iOS works? It writes header in one buffer, then data in the next one and so on. And it never wants more than around 170-180 bytes for each data chunk and that is why it ignores my large buffer?

Comment: how many buffers are you running? typically you want at least 3 buffers so you can process a buffer then immediately enqueue it back on the buffer queue.

Comment: I am running 50 buffers, sorry that was not included in the source code, but I have #define kNumberBuffers 50 in the .h file @Bamsworld

Comment: I tried changing to 3 buffers but same problem. Each buffer is minimal in lenght

Comment: It's not the number of buffers then. However I think 50 is overkill! I noticed you're using Audio Session Services class out of the AudioToolbox framework, where you call AudioSessionSetProperty. This class was fully deprecated in iOS7 - use AVAudioSession class from the AVFoundation framework instead to config your audio session.

Comment: Thanks @Bamsworld but I guess the deprecation is unrelated to the problems I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this eventually. Turns out that yes the encoding on iOS produces small and large chunks of data. I added a second phase buffer myself using NSMutableData and it worked perfectly.